# Nusoap Request message size limit

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

Is there a default limit on request message size in NuSoap? I am asking this
because when I send xml data with size 5225 KB using NuSOAP client to a
NuSOAP server I get the following response from the server.

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Cache-Control: private

Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8

Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5

Date: Wed, 26 Jun 2013 06:30:51 GMT

Content-Length: 441
```

I have tried looking at the error log files for apache and PHP, but nothing
can be found there.

Answer (score 0):

Since your server chokes on large requests, it may be requesting more memory than what is provided by default by PHP.

Check the PHP [memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) setting, and try to adjust it accordingly. You haven't specified which PHP version you're using, but by default this was set to 8MB prior to PHP 5.2.0, 16MB in PHP 5.2.0, and 128MB in newer versions. If you are using a PHP version older than 5.3.0, the default 8 - 16MB memory would be too little to process such a large XML document.

Comment: I am having PHP 5.2.5 version and memory_limit i have given is 128 MB.

Comment: There isn't enough information given, in order to find out the actual cause. "Internal server error" is pretty generic, I'm afraid. Try turning on PHP errors in case something more useful turns up

Comment: i have turned on PHP error , m not finding any type of error in PHP.